# Requirements to run Ruby on Rails on Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, requirements

I want to develop a website using Ruby on Rails. 
What is the requirements for the Server, i.e. what do I have to tell the admin what I need. I believe the server will be running on a machine that is already hosting some websites which use PHP. I dont know more about that so far, and it will probably be depending on my requirements.

As far as I understood from documentation and other questions the server needs to have ruby, rails installed. It also said that I could use cgi.

My problem is that I need a concrete list of things that my admin should provide.

Another question suggests that the only thing is to intall Phusion Passenger if I can use an Apache Werbserver. This would seem like an option maybe.

So what do I really need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger is the easiest way to go in a mixed environment.

A Rails app needs these things:

- ruby (ruby enterprise edition or MRI 1.9.2)
- rubygems
- sort of gems handled with bundler

You should try it with Passenger on Your local computer. Then you will see the list for the installation.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand the answer. So the Server would need Phusion Passenger plus ruby, rubygems and sort gems(what is this?) ?

Comment: Sort of gems I mean. Sorry for the typo. Rails depends on another libraries off course.